# C# capture pressed gamepad keys (Direct Input)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, gamepad, directinput

How to capture pressed gamepad keys (Direct Input) in C#?

I have searched but most of the sources seem outdated, will there be a simple API that allows me to capture these events?

I am making an app that captures all the keystrokes on a gamepad but I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XNA or MonoGame. They have simple API to detect pressed keys.
For example
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb197001(v=xnagamestudio.42)

Comment: It does not support dinput, only xinput. I would like to make an app that records the events of the gamepad dinput and then transform it to xinput with the valid client. But I can't get a good way to capture gamepad activity